# How to remove bitlocker if i forgot password and recovery key

Tags: bitlocker

How to remove bitlocker if i lost password and recovery key

I have installed Adobe photoshop from getintopcthen after some time my drive gets automatically enabled with bitlocker i don't that is because of that application of something else.

I have tried all stuff in CMD but still didn't succeed

Comment: Your drive is encrypted by bitlocker. Not just "locked" but a key. You cannot "bypass" it. A lock is like a padlock, breakable. Encryption is like entangling all your data to rubbish, only un-entanglable with the correct key.

Comment: Also, this is off topic here. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions.